# WinAPI and NTFS : reading longer paths

Tags: winapi, ntfs

NTFS allows for up to 32k characters in a fully-qualified path. WinAPI only allows for up to 248 characters for the full path minus the filename for compatibility reasons, and 255 total characters. Is there any way to use `DeviceIOControl()` to bypass this limitation and read any potentially-longer path strings? If that is possible, is there any way then to get a handle to a file whose full path name is longer than 255 characters?

Comment: Windows 10 now supports long filenames

Comment: ... if you double-opt-in for that, using the registry key and an application manifest element as described here: [Maximum Path Length Limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath). Note that the section I linked to suggests that you can use either registry key or manifest element to enable long paths, which is not true. You have to use **both**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most wide versions of file/path based functions in kernel32 has supported longer paths since at least Windows 2000 if you use the [`\\?\` path prefix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath).

If you look at `CreateFile` on MSDN for example it says:

> In the ANSI version of this function, the name is limited to MAX_PATH characters. To extend this limit to 32,767 wide characters, call the Unicode version of the function and prepend "\\?\" to the path.

Windows 10, version 1607 (Anniversary Update) and later allows you to access longer paths without a prefix if you add the longPathAware tag to your manifest or change the machine group policy.

Parts of the shell, `CreateProcess` and `LoadLibrary` does not support > MAX_PATH no matter what you do.

Comment: _"if you add the longPathAware tag to your manifest"_ -- On a similar question @eryksun pointed out to me, that the longPathAware tag alone is not sufficient to enable long paths. You have to set the registry value "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem LongPathsEnabled (Type: REG_DWORD" in *addition* to the manifest tag. The MSDN reference is imprecise in that regard. I guess the same applies to the group policy; it won't have any effect unless you also have the manifest tag.

Comment: I think maybe the policy works even without the manifest tag. It has been a while since I tested so I might be wrong though.

Comment: the implementation is changed. say in 1607 only registry checked, in 1709 both

Comment: File path handling and Unicode conversion are implemented in the user-mode runtime library in ntdll.dll. Historically both were limited to `MAX_PATH` because the goal was only to provide compatibility with legacy DOS (e.g. supporting DOS devices such as "NUL"), Windows 3.x, and Windows 9x applications. NT 4 added support  for the "\\?\" prefix, which allows bypassing all path normalization for Unicode paths in order to avoid legacy DOS path rules and limits. The cost is losing support for relative paths, forward slash as a path separator, and having to use the "\\?\UNC" device for UNC paths.